# Format author field in references

Tags: biblatex, biber

I am using biblatex/biber to create the biliography, currently with the following options:

```
\usepackage[style=authoryear, 
backend=biber, 
giveninits=true
]{biblatex}
```

I have the following exemplary entry in my bib file (with last names first, then first names)

```
@article{2018-MN,
    author = {HOOLEN, JASON and THOMPSON, RAY},
    title = {Exemplary Title},
    journal = {The Journal of Bibtex-Examples},
    volume = {1001},
    number = {1000},
    pages = {1-2}
}
```

My question is: How can I automatically fix the caps in the bibliography? I would like to have the names as follows: "Hoolen, Jason and Thompson, Ray", not "HOOLEN, JASON and THOMPSON, RAY".
Don't worry about the commas/exact formatting, this question is just to figure out how to fix the caps. Is there any other solution besides manually overwriting the names?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is absolutely something that should be fixed (once!) on the `.bib` file side of things (ideally even manually to make sure you don't accidentally catch something that doesn't need to be corrected).

But since you have tagged your question with `biblatex` and Biber, here is a sourcemap solution that converts ALL CAPS in name fields to Title casing. This should do the right thing for most people's names, but may well fail for corporate authors or complicated names. (That's why it's better to go through the `.bib` file manually and correct the names.)

```
\documentclass[british]{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{babel}
\usepackage{csquotes}

\usepackage[style=authoryear, maxnames=999, backend=biber]{biblatex}

\DeclareSourcemap{
  \maps[datatype=bibtex]{
    \map[foreach=setnames]{
      \step[fieldsource=\regexp{$MAPLOOP},
            match=\regexp{(\p{Lu})(\p{Lu}+)},
            replace=\regexp{$1\L$2}]
    }
  }
}

\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@article{2018-MN,
  author  = {HOOLEN, JASON and THOMPSON, RAY},
  title   = {Exemplary Title},
  journal = {The Journal of Bibtex-Examples},
  volume  = {1001},
  number  = {1000},
  pages   = {1-2}
}
\end{filecontents}
\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}
\addbibresource{biblatex-examples.bib}


\begin{document}
\cite{sigfridsson,2018-MN}
\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

[image: Hoolen, Jason and Ray Thompson]